# Typescript generated CssExports interface: how to import / compile?

Tags: typescript, webpack, sass

**Quick pass on the import problems:**

```
import style from "../sass/app.scss"
```

*Works on compilation, is undefined at runtime. TS interface is properly binded.*

```
import * as style from "../sass/app.scss"
TS2339: Property 'x' does not exist on type
```

*Doesn't work at compile time, but does at runtime.*

```
const styles = require("../sass/app.scss");
```

*Works fine, but I doesn't wan't to use CJS imports.*

Using v4.41.5 of webpack.

devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    ...
    "@types/node-sass": "4.11.0",
    "@types/redux-thunk": "2.1.0",
    "@babel/core": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "7.8.3",
    "babel-loader": "8.0.6",
    "style-loader": "1.1.3",
    "css-loader": "3.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "8.0.2",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "4.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "3.2.0",
    "node-sass": "4.13.1",
    "webpack": "4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.10.1",
    ...
  }
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.tsx',
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.s[ac]ss$/,
        use: [
          // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
          { loader: "style-loader" },
          { loader: "css-modules-typescript-loader"},  // to generate a .d.ts module next to the .scss file (also requires a declaration.d.ts with "declare modules '*.scss';" in it to tell TypeScript that "import styles from './styles.scss';" means to load the module "./styles.scss.d.td")
          // Translates CSS into CommonJS
          { loader: "css-loader", options: { modules: true } },  // to convert the resulting CSS to Javascript to be bundled (modules:true to rename CSS classes in output to cryptic identifiers, except if wrapped in a :global(...) pseudo class)
          // Compiles Sass to CSS
          { loader: "sass-loader" },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        use: 'ts-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
      }
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: [ '.tsx', '.ts', '.js', '.scss', '.css' ],
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 9000
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: "./src/index.html"
    })
  ]
};
```

**declarations.d.ts:**

```
declare module '*.scss' {
    export const content: {[className: string]: string};
}
```

**app.scss:**

```
.x {
  background-color: red;
}
```

**generated app.scss.d.ts:**

```
// This file is automatically generated.
// Please do not change this file!
interface CssExports {
  'app': string;
}
export const cssExports: CssExports;
export default cssExports;
```

Comment: The problem is that CJS <-> ESM translation isn't being handled for the style modules. It should just work. Are you using an old version of webpack, or any loaders? Make sure your dev dependencies are up to date.

Comment: I'm using latest version of each dependencies. I update the post with related dev dependencies versions.

Answer (score 1):

The important is using "css-modules-typescript-loader" after "style-loader" `use: ["style-loader", "css-modules-typescript-loader", "css-loader"],`.